# TypeScript 1.5 ES6 modules & .d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped seem incompatible

Tags: typescript, webstorm, ecmascript-6, typescript1.5

I'm using WebStorm for web-development & have recently upgraded from the built-in TypeScript 1.4 compiler to 1.5.3. However, not everything went as I wanted as the compiler began to yield errors prompting me to drop the `--module commonjs` parameter & switch to ES6 modules instead (I'm using `--target es6`). Having done that, I started getting errors saying that import assignments cannot be used when targeting ES6 & that I should use the new module syntax instead (error 1202). So I converted all my files, but apparently it wasn't enough as the `.d.ts` files installed via `tsd` from the DefinitelyTyped repo use the old syntax making the compiler keep giving the same errors.

I wrote a small converter for the `.d.ts` files, it works fairly well although occasionally makes me fix errors manually here & there. I'm wondering if there is a better workaround for this? Perhaps, I'm missing something?

P.S. Changing the `--target` to `es5` is not an option as the compiler would otherwise complain about absence of things like promises which I heavily use in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Changing the --target to es5 is not an option as the compiler would otherwise complain about absence of things like promises which I heavily use in my project.

Use `--target es5 --noLib` and then bring in `es6.lib.d.ts` manually.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The only problem occurring is the TS4091 error (loop contains block-scoped variable...), so I had to change the declaration of those variables from `let/const` back to `var`. I was using `--target es6` before to avoid this kind of stuff & would babelify everything upon build (since TypeScript lags far behind Babel in terms of ES6 support, I have (had) to use both). Also, WebStorm doesn't seem to support decorators yet, plus some issues with syntax highlighting.

Otherwise, everything else works fine, thank you!