# TypeScript: Good d.ts file for ES2015/ES6?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

The goal: Find a d.ts file that'll teach TypeScript the changes in ES2015/ES6.

[TypeScript 1.5 ES6 modules & .d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped seem incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568198/typescript-1-5-es6-modules-d-ts-files-from-definitelytyped-seem-incompatible) (Jul 2015) references using es6.lib.d.ts.

[error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431923/error-ts2339-property-endswith-does-not-exist-on-type-string) (Dec 2015) points to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts.

Note the difference between the file titles!

I looked on `typings` and found neither `es6.lib.d.ts` nor `lib.es6.d.ts`.

I copied the `lib.es6.d.ts` cited above and cited it in my programs (`/// <reference path="./typings/lib.es6.d.ts" />`); the compiler tilts when processing that file. Line 132 there is

```
readonly prototype: Object;
```

Line 132 is the first occurrence of `readonly` in the file. The compiler points at `readonly` and reports

```
error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
```

Anyone know how to teach ES6 to TypeScript? Or to work around teaching it? (I'd love to use ES6 features, of course!) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone know how to teach ES6 to TypeScript

With the *latest compiler* (and you really should use that https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#nightly-typescript) you can use the `--lib es6` option.

## More

More on `lib` option : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6974

(PS: its supported in alm https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `ES6` as you target and you have taught ES6 to typescript.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is the runtime might not understand the generated ES6 (e.g. old browsers). You really just want the `lib` to change but still target ES5

Comment: @basarat and @Zen: I appreciate inputs from both of you. My tsconfig.json already had Zen's settings. It now also has `"target": "ES3", "lib": "ES6". I want to write in ES6 and have my output understood by every browser out there. If I run into problems, I'll set "target" to "ES5". Thanks! And ... related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200297/typescript-how-can-i-get-a-clean-compile