# TypeScript: How can I get a clean compile?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I hope this is simple!

`TypeScript` Version 1.9.0-dev.20160512 (available from `npm install -g typescript@next` and recommended by @basarat)
`Node` v5.11.0
`Windows` 10.0.10586

file 1, u1c.ts

```
import * as u1u from "./u1u.ts"
let p = u1u.Promise
console.log(`from u1c.ts`)
```

file 2, u1u.ts

```
console.log(`from u1u.ts`)    
export let Promise = require(`bluebird`) //http://bluebirdjs.com
```

file 3, tsconfig.json (**relevant part only**); I want to write in ES6 and get output in ES3 (on the presumption that all browsers out there will know about it).

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "complierOptions": {
        "lib": "ES6",
        "target": "ES3"
    }
}
```

result 1

```
>tsc u1c.ts
u1u.ts(2,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Can't find "require"? Sounds like it doesn't know about Node.js. Let's teach it! `typings` gives me access to a fifth version of node.d.ts last changed 2016-05-09; I pulled it in and pointed at it.

new u1u.ts

```
/// <reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts" />  // <==== new line, only change
console.log(`from u1u.ts`)    
export let Promise = require(`bluebird`) //http://bluebirdjs.com
```

result 2 (same as result 1)

```
>tsc u1c.ts
u1u.ts(2,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

I'm out of ideas. How can I get a clean compile?

Thanks in advance for any time and ideas you offer!

Answer (score 1):

> Can't find "require"? Sounds like it doesn't know about Node.js

Definitely a good idea to include `node.d.ts`. However you *should* use `import/require` instead of `var/require` (or `let/require`, `const/require`). The difference is that `import` tells TypeScript that its is a module. ([more on modules](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html))

> `/// <reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts" />  // <==== new line, only change`

The issue is the path is wrong. Suspect you need `main` (or `browser`) in there.

PS: Recommend using `tsconfig.json` (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/tsconfig.html) with `exclude` to rule out the version of typings you don't want.

Comment: Apparently, I'll add more to your book about things users trip on during their journey to TypeScript expertise. Thanks for the help and the developing book. About your second point: I had copied `node.d.ts` there from where `typings` put it. I'll learn a better way. About the rest: (1) I seem to be blocked from `let NodeDTs = require("node")` by `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.` (2) I seem to be blocked from `import * as NodeDTs from "./typings/node/node.d.ts"` by `'C:/<path>/typings/node/node.d.ts' is not a module.` (3) I am unfamiliar with your `import/require` notation.

Comment: I've looked at my `node.d.ts`; the most recent I can find is for Node 4.x; I'm using 5.11. I'll try the `globals.d.ts` route your book recommends. And, I _think_ I understand your `import/require` notation. You're encouraging me to use `import nodeDTs = require("../typings/globals.d.ts")`? (I found that in the TS 1.8 docs.) But ... I define `require` inside that file. There's something I don't understand yet.